# ssh-agent on ubuntu rapidly restarts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I am attempting to use `ssh-agent` on `Ubuntu 13.10` so that I will not have to enter my passphrase to unlock a key every time I want to use ssh or git.

As you can see below, `ssh-agent` appears to be restarting for some reason. These commends were executed within a period of less than 5 seconds:

```
andrew@zaphod:~$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-pqm5J0s70NxG/agent.2820; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=2821; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 2821;
andrew@zaphod:~$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-VpkOH2WKjT1M/agent.2822; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=2823; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 2823;
andrew@zaphod:~$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-EQ6X9JHNiBOO/agent.2824; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=2825; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 2825;
andrew@zaphod:~$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-8Iij8kFkaapz/agent.2826; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=2827; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 2827;
andrew@zaphod:~$
```

My guess is that `ssh-agent` is crashing, but how would I know? What log file would it log to?

Comment: You can get more information by running `ssh-agent -d`. This will put ssh-agent in debug mode.

Comment: maybe try `gdb ssh-agent` and type run, or `strace ssh-agent` to go further with debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have started the `ssh-agent` multiple times in parallel. Note that `ssh-agent` goes to background after starting it, meaning it will detach from the terminal and creating a new process group (which's parent is the init process). See UNIX [daemons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29).

You can verify this using:

```
ps -F x | grep 'ssh-agent'
```

The output will look like:

```
2821 ?        Ss     0:00 ssh-agent
2823 ?        Ss     0:00 ssh-agent
2825 ?        Ss     0:00 ssh-agent
2827 ?        Ss     0:00 ssh-agent
```

Comment: Implying the daemon "backgrounds" rather than dying

Comment: Have added that information.